# UTF-8 без BOM

Tags: кодировка, html

Листинг html-кода страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Мая страница</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ico.png" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
...
```

Кодировка UTF-8 без BOM, сам сайт лежит на денвере, весь русский текст в кракозябрах!
Что делать?

Comment: А как же `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: @Kirpich643, Покажите кстати кракозябры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ох, уж этот Денвер... В корне сайта создаем, если его нет, файл .htaccess и прописываем строку:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: Deonis Спасибо помогло